# Function apply_filters() used to add unwanted content in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function

My theme has a line of code which add **extra stuff** to the normal code:

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $desc); ?>
```

That some extra stuff (html code) is what I want to remove. If I change the theme PHP code as shown below, the extra stuff is not added anymore:

```
<?php echo $desc; ?>
```

But I want to find where it is. I've looked everywhere in the theme files/database and can't seem to find where the extra code is added through the **apply_filters()** function.

If anyone can explain how that function works, maybe I can find where the extra content comes from. Thanks.

**Further info:** if Wordpress is in Maintenance Mode (via a plugin), the extra code is not added!

Comment: Disable all of your plugins and check again. Chances are at least one of them is hooking into `the_content` to add that "extra stuff" you want removed.

Comment: You are a life saver, I'd never have thought that a plugin would hijack that function. Thank you, it's solved now!